# jquery menu dissappears after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive menu, and everything is working, only when i resize the menu, test it with some clicks and then resize back or put on any other viewport size, the menu disappears and i have to refresh the site to have the menu again.

Here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.menu > li:has(ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI

    $(".menu").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Izbornik</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).slideToggle(600);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu").slideToggle(300);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story

});
```

I commented the code so if anyone is willing to help me can see what i did.

css:

```
    .menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  display: block;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #1a2b3e;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .7em 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0 none;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu > li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
.menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu > li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #1a2b3e;
}
.menu > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
  background: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
}
.menu > li > ul > li a {
  padding: .2em 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:last-child {
  width: 17%;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:last-child > ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 49.666%;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Chrome, Safari */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  /* IE 11 */
  display: inline-block;
  /* Actually FF 20+ */
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: -5px 0;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .menu-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > li a {
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > li > ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > li > ul > li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Here is the live link http://jsfiddle.net/v12z4e66/1/

When you resize the menu to the mobile media query and you toggle the menu, when you resize back to desktop the menu is not there and you have to refresh the page

Comment: paste your html & css also :)

Comment: @mwl Thanks in advance if you will help me. I pasted CSS in edit. HTML is classic structure

Comment: please update this jsfidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/v12z4e66/ (clasic structure is not clear for me).

Comment: @mwl I did, thank you !! http://jsfiddle.net/v12z4e66/1/
See when menu is in mobile media query and you toggle it, then resize to desktop width its not there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideToggle()` add inline styles to DOM. When you clicked on `.mobileMenu` your html in devtools looks that:

```
<ul class="menu" style="display: none;">
    ...
</ul>
```

Instead of using animations in jQuery use classes, for example:
`addClass('show-on-menu);` or `toggleClass('show-on-mobile);`

Then in your styles you can do what you want in media queries, so `.show-on-mobile` can be ignored on screen > 960px;

Look on updated jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v12z4e66/3/

Comment: Thank you so much, its working, that was what i was looking for!!! Its been killing me for weeks! Is there a way i can animate that, maybe with .animate() ? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, but remember - jQuery `animate()` also works on inline styles. I recommend you css transitions instead of JS animations.